# using datasource with CheckedListBox and all items selected

Tags: c#, datasource, selected, checkedlistbox

I using this code to create and add item for DataSource in my CheckedListBox.

```
CheckedListBox1.DataSource = DataSource1.Tables[0];
CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Col_Name";
```

How do I create all item selected (without using loop)?

Comment: you want to use datasource or want to add item thruogh loop???

Comment: CheckedListBox.SelectedItems is a read-only property. Individual ListItem Selected property is not data-bound. You will need to use a loop (or a LINQ expression).

Comment: @Pranav i not use loop in CheckedListBox, only in DataSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment earlier, I'm posting an answer: it can't be done without a loop.

This will select all the items:

```
CheckedListBox1.DataSource = DataSource1.Tables[0];
CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Col_Name";

for (int i = 0; i < CheckedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    CheckedListBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
}
```

This will check all the items:

```
CheckedListBox1.DataSource = DataSource1.Tables[0];
CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Col_Name";

for (int i = 0; i < CheckedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
```